# Migrating WSO2 Definitions to AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, aws-api-gateway, migrate, api-gateway

Disclaimer: I have almost 0-knowledge on API development.

The objective is not to write API, but to port an existing definition.

Our current API Setup is a WSO2 Cluster API Manager residing in 3 different EC2 instances. One for both Publisher and Store, one for Gateway, one for Key Manager.

I've already took the time to review the config, so I at least know how the three components are 'talking' to each other.

What I've found out so far is that the API Definitions is somewhere in a path "*/gateway/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/" and there are XMLs in there which define the API. Reading through it, it seems that the fields are identical to the ones I can see in AWS API Gateway. So I know there must be a way to port them over.

However, beyond this, I'm completely lost as to what my next step is. How deep of an understanding of API should I have to be able to successfully do this? Is there a tool I can use to Import the API into AWS API Gateway? Or export from WSO2? I'm a bit stuck because the only thing that I can see right now that could help is for me to study WSO2 and API Definitions, but we don't exactly have enough time to do that with the time constraints we're given.

Any step in the right direction would be appreciate. Thank you!

EDIT: The reason that we're looking at migrating is because maintenance has been a nightmare. We've ran into so many critical problems regarding the API whenever we have to do some regular cleanups, not to mention that 3 EC2 Instances are costing us as well, so we're looking for a more lightweight, easier-to-maintain option.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to migrate the API definitions, you may try to import an API to API Gateway using a Swagger file (i.e., OpenAPI definition) [1].

Can you try to export a Swagger file from the WSO2 API manager? If yes, you can follow the instructions in [1] to import an API in the API Gateway.

Regarding the total migration of the API Manager (i.e., API definitions, endpoint definitions, security policies, caching/throttling policies,  etc), I would suggest you to conduct a proper feasibility study to make sure whether the features used in your API manager can be translated into the features offered by the API Gateway.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/import-export-api-endpoints.html

Comment: Looks like there's really a bunch of reading we need to do, huh. Feasibility study... looks like this problem is bigger than expected. For now, I'll look into exporting properly from WSO2 API Manager. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hi, I mentioned about a feasibility study assuming your API Manager is accepting production traffic of the users (i.e., your clients). The users may have implemented their API clients based on the features offered by the API Manager (e.g., custom headers for authentication/usage tracking etc). Also the message mediation features could be different among each other. You will need to review how the API Gateway supports such features and update the API configuration/definition accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I'll investigate those. Thank you for the reply.